# Generating a DELETE script on all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have a medium sized database, structure wise, and we need to go for a soft delete, to a hard delete. Part of the process is to actually delete rows where they have been soft deleted, before removing the Deleted column. I have generated a list of deletes, but I may hit a foreign key exception.

so, I ordered by 'object_id', in the hope that tables get added in an order and the object_id increased. No tables have been added since deployment.

So, would this be suitable?

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM [' + ss.name + '].[' + st.name + '] WHERE DELETED IS NOT NULL'
FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss
ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
WHERE type='U'
AND st.name NOT IN ('JobRunLog', 'Log')
AND st.Object_ID IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT(st.object_id) 
    FROM sys.tables st
    INNER JOIN sys.columns cc 
        ON st.object_id = cc.object_id 
    AND cc.name = 'DELETED'
)
ORDER BY st.object_id DESC
```

I'm going backwards on object_id as I want to delete the last tables added, first. They could only have been created if the FK existed.

Comment: I assume they don't have cascade delete on the FK?

Comment: If your database is not very big, taking a backup copy and running this script on that database will be an easy way for you to test your script and fine tune it further.